# How do I scrape a rating within a span

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to scrape the Skytrax website and so far this is mode code.

```
url  = "https://www.airlinequality.com/airline-reviews/british-airways/page/1/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

reviews = soup.find_all('article', class_="comp_media-review-rated")
for item in reviews:
    title = item.find('h2', class_="text_header").text.strip()
    meta = item.find('h3', class_="text_sub_header").text.strip()
    main_review = item.find("div", class_="text_content").text.strip()
    aircraft = item.find_all('td', class_="review-value")[0].text
    traveller_type = item.find_all('td', class_="review-value")[1].text
    seat_type = item.find_all('td', class_="review-value")[2].text
    route = item.find_all('td', class_="review-value")[3].text
    travel_date = item.find_all('td', class_="review-value")[4].text
    seat_comfort = item.find_all('span')
    cabin_staff_service = item.find().text
    food_beverages = item.find().text
    inflight_entertainment = item.find().text
    ground_service = item.find().text
    value_for_money = item.find().text
    recommended = item.find().text
```

Now I need the total number of reviews from the seat_comfort section and this what the code for that section looks like

```
<td class = "review-rating-stars stars">
<span class = "star fill">1</span>
<span class = "star fill">2</span>
<span class = "star fill">3</span>
<span class = "star">4</span>
<span class = "star">5</span>
</td>
```

How can I scrape this?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. Are you asking how to get a total number of reviews or actual number based on the star-rating for a single review?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the quantity of starfill classes, you can use the functions *find_all* and *len*:

```
star = soup.find_all('span',{"class":"star fill"})
print(len(star))
```

The function *find_all* return a list of all *span* tags that have class equal to *star fill* and the *len* function will show the length of this list.

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I really read about this yesterday!